# Big FAT32 volume is detected as RAW under Windows

Tags: windows, partitioning, formatting, fat32

I created 450 GB FAT32 volume in GPT partition table using `mkfs.fat`. It works without any problem on Linux. When I connect it to computer with Windows 10, it says it is RAW and wants to format it.

```
/dev/sdxX: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "mkfs.fat", Bytes/sector 4096, sectors/cluster 64, reserved sectors 64, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 2099200, sectors 117964800 (volumes > 32 MB), FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 1856, reserved 0x1, serial number 0x7163f35a, label: "XXXXX      "
```

Answer (score 0):

I reformatted it and tried again. It works now.

Old configuration:

```
/dev/sdxX: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "mkfs.fat", Bytes/sector 4096, sectors/cluster 64, reserved sectors 64, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 2099200, sectors 117964800 (volumes > 32 MB), FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 1856, reserved 0x1, serial number 0x7163f35a, label: "XXXXX      "
```

New configuration:

```
/dev/sdxX: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x58+2, OEM-ID "mkfs.fat", sectors/cluster 128, reserved sectors 128, Media descriptor 0xf8, sectors/track 63, heads 255, hidden sectors 945817600, sectors 524288000 (volumes > 32 MB), FAT (32 bit), sectors/FAT 32000, reserved 0x1, serial number 0xf6f03521, label: "XXXXX      "
```

See difference in `Bytes/sector 4096` (the new configuration has 512).

Correct command for formatting:

```
mkfs.fat /dev/sdxX -F 32 -n XXXXX -S 512 -s 128
```

---

Windows can't use FAT volumes with Bytes/sector (`-S`) set to value that is not 512.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for posting in our forum!
1. please run cmd command ”chkdsk” to check disk.

2. It is not recommended to format 450G disks into FAT32. NTFS format is recommended.
   Hope this information can help you. If you have any questions, please let me know.
   Best Regards,
   Daniel

Comment: `chkdsk` does not run on RAW volumes, IIRC. I tried reformatting and I am going to post new state in ~5 hours (I can't use Windows at the moment).

Comment: I know it is not the best option but I want to store the data in filesystem that can be used on nearly all operating systems. NTFS, ext2/3/4, btrfs, exFAT and others are not compatible with so many OSes.